# How to fix debug console cutting string in visual studio code (flutter)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

How to fix this issue when trying to view string or copying value in string in flutter gets shortened with three dots ("longtext...") in Flutter?

[image]

[image]

Is there a solution for this? Is the vscode team working on a solution for this?

Comment: There's an open feature request for it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94937

Comment: can this not be solved by using the `debug.console.wordWrap` setting?

Comment: I am not sure it is the same problem in that issue. And no, that settings does not solve the issue.